# How to make my SDL game run on another computer

Tags: c++, dependencies, sdl, sdl-2, portability

I have made a small game on my mac using SDL and aim to make it run on my friend's mac who does not have SDL installed.

In the files I have included `libSDL2.a` and `libSDL2_image.a`, but do I need to also include everything they depend on? Using `sdl2-config --static-libs output` it appears the list of their dependancies is quite long, and I'm not even sure where they all exist on my computer.

I don't want to have to install SDL onto her computer before I compile the game on it, I want the program to be stand-alone, without having to install anything on it anyone beforehand. Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to give your friend any files that your program requires to run. In other words, if your program only requires that you have a file like "SDL2.dll" or something similar, these files just need to be in the same folder as whatever exe file you have. (This is based on my experience in Visual Studio, if this isn't the case for your engine please let me know which engine you are using and I will try to assist you further).

Comment: OP is linking SDL statically, there's no _dylib_ involved (which is macOS _dll_) so all the functions are already linked with the final executable.